# Keyboard not recognised at luks screen

Tags: keyboard, encryption, luks, 19.04

I have just installed 19.04 and I have having an issue wih my keyboard at the luks password screen. My keyboard is a wired corsair K95 - connected via a USB3 port.

At Grub the keyboard works fine. But once the system is at the password input screen for luks either the lights on the keyboard go out or the lights stay on but either way I can't enter any input.

My current solution is to keep unplugging and re-plugging the keyboard until the system recognises it. Eventually it does and everything seems to work fine from there.

So from my very limited knowledge (Ubuntu noob), it seems some detection setting needs to be changed. Any assistance on what this might be (or any other diagnosis) is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

S

Comment: This is just a thought, but maybe check your BIOS of your system to see if you can set the USB to Legacy mode so that it shouldn't need a driver to work.

Comment: A good idea @Terrance. Will try that and post with results.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have answered my own question. The keyboard needed a bios update. This coupled with switching the polling switch to "BIOS" seems to have resolved my issue. Hope this helps anyone else having issues with the K95 RGB model.

Thanks

S